# I'm using fancyBox for a video gallery, but it's not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fancybox, open-source

```css
 html, body {
      margin: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      
    }
h1 {
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 85px;
    color: black;
}
h2 {
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 65px;
    color: black;
}


    button {
      font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      font-size: 17px;
      font-weight:normal;
      color: white;
      background-color: Transparent;
      border: 2px solid white;
    }

    #head
    {
display: none;
   }

a {
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#headSecond {
          font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      font-size: 21px;
      font-weight:normal;
      color: black;
      padding: 2px;
      margin-left: 1em;
     
}
#galleryPos {
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: 3em;
}
#imgLeft {
    width:188px;
    height:32px;
    down: 2;
    padding: 0px;
  margin-left: 0em;
}

#headButton {

font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      font-size: 17px;
     
      font-weight:normal;
      color: white;
      background-color: Transparent;
      border: 2px solid white;
      margin-left: 2em;
      

}
#headButton2 {

font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
      font-size: 17px;
      font-weight:normal;
      color: white;
      background-color: Transparent;
      border: 2px solid white;
      margin-left: 2em;


}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      
              <link rel = "stylesheet" href="main.css">
              <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.0.47/jquery.fancybox.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/3.0.47/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>


    </head>
      
        <body>
<div style="background-color:gray;color:white;padding:18px;">

<image id="imgLeft" src="rabbit2.png"/>

<a href="home.html">    <button id="headButton">Home</button> </a>
<a href="photo.html">   <button id ="headButton2"> Photography </button> </a>
</div>
<h2 id ="headSecond" >Demo Reel</h2>

<br>
<br>
<div id="galleryPos">

  <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/geZD5_OVCiQ">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="OU.jpg" />
  </a>
  <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7fcBoTFyQcM">
      <img class="img-responsive" src="okc.jpg" />
 </a>
<a data-fancybox="gallery" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/_jNChDq8foY">
<img class"img-responsive" src="Puebla.jpg"/>

</a>


</div>
        </body>
</html>
```

I'm using [fancyBox](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancybox)'s open-source project. I'm new to using JavaScript/jQuery.

```
<link rel = "stylesheet" href="main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dist/jquery.fancybox.min.css">
```

I've typed this in the head of the HTML and also used this for my YouTube video gallery:

```
<div id="galleryPos">
    <a data-fancybox="gallery" href="https://www.youtube.com/embed/geZD5_OVCiQ">
        <img class="img-responsive" src="OU.jpg">
    </a>
</div>
```

I used an image OU.jpg to be an image on display before clicking on the link:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="dist/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
<script src="main.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you show the page's full source code?

Comment: Michael, the code you provided works fine. http://codepen.io/anon/pen/MprWWQ Do you have any errors in your browser console?

Comment: i'm now using the web js links Michael Coker used in the codepen... now the browser console isn't picking up the links to the youtube videos, however it is getting the gray background box. I also uploaded the css and html file for this page

Comment: I got it to work, now i have to fix a few issues but here's a copy of the unfinished site https://santos2k1.github.io/white-rabbit/home.html... thanks